# How to reduce the ssl record buffer size

Tags: ssl, encryption, openssl

I have ssl server which can decrypt the encrypted data received from ssl client.
Due to limitations server side read buffer size is 1500 , if the client sends the encrypted data with in 1500 mtu server is decrypting as expected.
There is a scenario where the client trying to upload file to the server.
During upload client sents the encrypted data length around 16k.
Which is received as tcp segments server unable to reassemble them.
Is there option available to make client to sent encrypted data with in mtu i.e 1500.

Comment: Since you've tagged this with openssl see [SSL_CTX_set_max_send_fragment](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_CTX_set_max_send_fragment.html). As for other TLS stacks see their respective documentation on how to set [max fragment length](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6066#page-8)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the client and what extensions they support (as well as what the server supports, though hopefully you have more control over that). What you want is the [Record Size Limit Extension (RFC 8449)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8449). OpenSSL does not support this, though there is an [open PR](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/18248) that you could explore. mbedtls also does not support this extension. [PR #7455](https://github.com/Mbed-TLS/mbedtls/pull/7455) may be worth looking at. I don't know any TLS libraries that do support this extension currently.

If you control the client (or can reverse the relationship), you can use the [Maximum Fragment Length extension (RFC 6066)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6066#section-4). However, this only permits the **client** to set the maximum fragment size, not the server. [MFL is supported by OpenSSL.](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_split_send_fragment.html)

Comment: Unfortunately i didn't have control over client and i am using openssl library.